# Подскажите слайдер под React в котором можно реализовать все последующие карточки меньшего размера

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slider

Всем привет, начал изучать React и в первом макете который начал верстать на React есть слайдер, который я не знаю как реализовать, не могу найти подобный слайдер, может кто подскажет, где посмотреть ?)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Фото слайдера.

Comment: Например - https://react-slick.neostack.com/     Этот слайдер используется не только в React, но и во всех почти веб-разработках. Так же везде используется - https://swiperjs.com/react  во всех веб-разработках. Первый легче для понимания, второй больше для тех, кто в JS хорошо разбирается.

Comment: А такой внешний вид можно сделать с помощью стилей.

Comment: Евгений, спасибо) Как обычно бывает, долго не мог понять как его реализовать, но только создал опрос, сразу же в голову начали приходить мысли и уже вроде как понял, как его реализовать ))